# How to authorize a private route with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying out server side authentication with an api I've built. All of my routes have been tested and seem to be working fine on postman. I'm using Axios on the front end, and all public routes work perfectly. Logging in using Axios works fine too. It's the private routes that are the problem. I'm used to Google's api for front end authentication, so I can't seem to figure out how to authorize private routes.

**axios.js**

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

const login = () => {
  Axios({
    url: '/auth/login',
    baseURL: 'http://<ip address>/api/v1',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      email: '<email>',
      password: '<password>'
    }
  }).then(res => sessionStorage.setItem('auth', res.data.token))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

So the code above works fine, but I may be going in the wrong direction by saving the token to session storage in the browser. The code below is the private postArticle route. where I get the following message, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`.

**axios.js**

```
const postArticle = () => {
  Axios({
    url: '/articles',
    baseURL: 'http://<ip address>/api/v1',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      "title": "New Title",
      "subtitle": "Optional Subtitle",
      "description": "Small Intro to Social Media Integration",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Aliquam purus...",
      "tag": [
        "Mobile Development",
        "Diary"
      ]
    }
  }).then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

When I console.log the token it comes out right, but I'm not sure how I need to change postArticle to take in the default headers.

Comment: where "Axios" come from? is a new instance ? you are setting defaults over "axios", so your api call should be axios({})

Comment: I'm doing this in React so the axios npm package is imported with a capital A. Also, according to the documentation config defaults arent supposed to be within the `axios({})` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Login was done properly. Just needed to bring the default into the headers for postArticle.

```
const postArticle = () => {
  Axios({
    headers: {
      'Authorization': Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'],
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: '/articles',
    baseURL: 'http://67.207.83.201/api/v1',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      "title": "Another New Title",
      "subtitle": "Optional Subtitle",
      "description": "Small Intro for Play Play Play",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Tortor consequat id porta nibh.",
      "tag": [
        "Mobile Development",
        "Diary"
      ]
    }
  }).then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```